# How to escape characters in WMI query

Tags: c#, wmi

I tried to use the following code to create WMI query:

```
string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.PNPDeviceID='" + device["PNPDeviceID"].ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\")
                        + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
```

But if the `query` variable looks like `ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.PNPDeviceID='USBSTOR\\DISK&VEN_FLASH&PROD_DRIVE_SM_USB20&REV_1100\\7214030310011150&0'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` it gives me "Invalid object path" exception.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

What is the appropriate way to escape all characters in the WMI query then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong property chosen to query `ASSOCIATORS OF`. The `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` class represents an association between a disk drive and a partition existing on it with next *relational* properties:

```
==>wmic path Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition get /value

Antecedent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1""
Dependent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0""

Antecedent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1""
Dependent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #1""

Antecedent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0""
Dependent="\\PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0""

==>
```

Hence, using the `"Where AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"` clause, you could query `ASSOCIATORS OF` either

```
string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + dd_ID
                    + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
```

or

```
string query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + pp_ID
                    + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
```

Here, with respect to the above scenario (see `wmic` output):

- `dd_ID` could be either

  - `"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0"` or
  - `"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1"` (two-items collection returned, of course) and
- `pp_ID` could be either

  - `"Disk #0, Partition #0"` or
  - `"Disk #1, Partition #0"` or
  - `"Disk #1, Partition #1"`.

I have tested above queries in all data combinations in `VBScript` and hope it should work in `c#` as well (exclusively of there could come necessity of escaping backslashes in `c#`).